# How to simulate BidEvictedEvent for EC2 spot instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spot-instances

I have an application load balancer that contains several EC2 spot instances.

I found that one of them was terminated because of [`BidEvictedEvent`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html), i.e., someone requested a spot instance with a price higher than mine.

The `BidEvictedEvent` made my web service unavailable (`502 bad gateway`) for a few seconds.

So I want to execute a script that detaches the EC2 from the auto-scaling group before it got terminated.

Now my question is, how can I simulate `BidEvictedEvent` so that I can make sure that my script got executed correctly?

I've tried terminating the EC2 instance from AWS console. But this doesn't create `502 bad gateway` for the client of my web service when there's no script executed before EC2 termination.

I use the method mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-spot-instance-termination-notices/) to monitor when the BidEvictedEvent occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided is for the old way of detecting spot interruption notices. Maybe this is exactly how you want to do this, but these days you would use **CloudWatch Event** rule for `EC2 Spot Instance Interruption Warning`.

Using the rule, you could setup a lambda function which would perform actions on your instance scheduled for the termination. These action can include removal from ASG, or running custom commands on it through `SSM Command Run`.

What's more you could easily **simulate** the event, as it has known format and you could invoke the lambda with the test event.

More info about this is in [Taking Advantage of Amazon EC2 Spot Instance Interruption Notices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/taking-advantage-of-amazon-ec2-spot-instance-interruption-notices/). The example of spot interruption event that your lambda function would need to process/simulate is:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "1e5527d7-bb36-4607-3370-4164db56a40e",
  "detail-type": "EC2 Spot Instance Interruption Warning",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1b:instance/i-0b662ef9931388ba0"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": "i-0b662ef9931388ba0",
    "instance-action": "terminate"
  }
}
```